# Inputting new line to a text file using user input

Tags: python-3.x

I need help in this code. I want to separate the given details using the newline but this is the output I'm getting.

```
John 12-12345January 1, 1990Unknown
```

How do I separate this to:

```
John
12-12345
January 1,1990
Unknown
```

This is my code:

```
while True:
f = open("Personal details of the students", "wt+")
f.write(str(input("PLease enter your name: ")))
f.write(str(input("Please enter your Student Number: ")))
f.write(str(input("Please enter your birthday: ")))
f.write(str(input("Please enter your complete adress: ")))
next_fill = input("Do you want to try again? Y|N: ")
if next_fill[0] in "Yy":
    continue
elif next_fill[0] in "Nn":
    print("Thanks for filling out the form. Have a nice day.")
    break
f.close()
```

Thanks guys for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix is to add a `\n` after the user input:

```
f.write(str(input("PLease enter your name: ") + "\n"))
f.write(str(input("Please enter your Student Number: ") + "\n"))
f.write(str(input("Please enter your birthday: ") + "\n"))
f.write(str(input("Please enter your complete adress: ") + "\n"))
```

Comment: Same output. john123-1234unknownunknown

Comment: Oh sorry! You meant after the input, I thought you added it inside the parenthesis.